Can ambiguity arise from the "that" in a that-clause being misinterpreted as a determiner?
In some cases, it seems that the word "that" could be interpreted as being a determiner or as being part of a that-clause. Consider the statements A, B and C. A, B and C are placeholders that each represent an actual statement in English. For example, A could be the bowl is green or set X is a subset of set Y. Consider the following compound statement:

If A then it must be that B and that C

The intention of writing If A then it must be that B and that C instead of If A then B and C is to avoid the misinterpretation C and if A then B by introducing a that-clause that C. I will first give a mathematical example of the issue in question and then a non-mathematical example of the issue in question to demonstrate that this issue is a general grammar issue in any English sentence.
Mathematical example
Let A be integer y is even, let B be integer y is not in Y and let C be integer x is in set X. In this scenario, it seems that the statement If integer y is even then it must be that integer y is not in Y and that integer x is in set X seems ambiguous because the second that in the statement could be interpreted as a determiner introducing the noun integer y (rather than being interpreted as part of a that-clause). In other words, If integer y is even then it must be that integer y is not in Y and that integer x is in set X could be interpreted as two unrelated/independent statements conjoined with an and where that integer x refers to an integer x introduced in a previous sentence.
Non-mathematical example
If instead, A is I am at the supermarket, B is I am out of the house and C is Fred is at school, then the same ambiguity seems to exist. The statement If I am at the supermarket then it must be that I am out of the house and that Fred is at school seems ambiguous because the second that could be a determiner introducing Fred and not part of a that-clause. In other words, that Fred is at school could be interpreted as an independent statement where that Fred refers to a particular Fred (e.g. that Fred, not this Fred).
In any case, if we remove the second that, If A then it must be that B and C could be misinterpreted as C and if A then B. So clearly the that cannot be removed.
So am I correct about the that being ambiguous in these examples? If not, why? Furthermore, are the following reworded statements unambiguous?

If A then it is true that B and true that C.

For example If there is glass on the floor it is true that a glass was knocked off the shelf and true that someone did not clean up the mess.


If A then it is both true that B and true that C.

For example If X is a strict subset of Y then it is both true that integer x is in Y for every x in X and true that |X| < |Y|.


If A then it is both the case that B and that C.

For example If I am playing guitar then it is both the case that I had nothing more important to do and that baby Emily is asleep.




This seems more of a question for mathematicians or logicians, since it's about very specific technical use of language. In normal English there is a possible ambiguity with mass nouns e.g. "I think that rice is a good crop" (is it all rice or some specific rice).

@StuartF Yes, it is, but those people still have to comply with grammatical principles when it becomes necessary to translate the symbols into intelligible sentences.


If A then it must be that B and that C are the same. That might feasibly mean either of 2) If A then it must be that this B and that C are the same, OR  3) If A then it must be that that B and that C are the same. But only in the somewhat unlikely context that there are two possible B's within the current frame of reference (this B and that B :) And that's not to mention the possibility of there being one or more alternative C's to that C! But this is a question for English Language Learners


@FumbleFingers This is not the language of mathematical logic: "the same" is not used. "That B" is meaningless since there is only one B, which is a proposition also callled "(logical) statement"). No demonstrative is used with statements.

What is the point of those? Why don't you write out your examples with some spacing so our eyes don't glaze over?

Contrived examples that might just appear in logic exams are not sufficiently normal-usage-orientated for ELU.

@LPH: since there is only one B ??? But I specifically said in my comment in the somewhat unlikely context that there are two possible B's within the current frame of reference (this B and that B :) It's irrelevant that this OP seems not to understand the difference between contextualized natural language and "unambiguous" mathematical notation. My above comment stands as proof that the word "that" could be interpreted as being a determiner or as being part of a that-clause.

@FumbleFingers The concepts of mathematical logic are rudimentary; there is no notion of a demonstrative function in it; it follows that in the transcriptions from symbol to text, demonstratives have no meaning. The spoken forms of the symbolic language that are most English-like are derived from the symbols and are strictly representative of what they mean; there is no room (very little) for free expression; certain synonyms are allowed, though. // A symbol such as B (controversially called a variable (propositional variable)), is in fact a fixed element of a set, it does not vary; (1/2)

@FumbleFingers B is merely a name you give for convenience to something like "The sun is hot", "5=1", (wrong or false). There is only one statement "5=1".  It is utterly meaningless to speak of 'this "5=1"'.  You will have noticed that the OP always starts with a definition of A, B, and C, saying "A is …", "B is …",… (2/2)

You can't have such an indeterminacy: if you have a taht-clause, then, necessarily there is a verb somewhere after "that". In the particular case of mathematical text, that (that) you are showing, an ellipsis of the verb and of some words has to be taken into account.

If A then it must be that B and that C
In proper English you have to read that as "f A is true then it must be true that B is true and that  C is (also) true.

If A then it must be that B and  C
*This construction where the second "that" is not used is ambiguous; it can be interpreted as either "If A then it must be that (B and  C)" or as "(If A then it must be that B) and  C".


There might be conventions that have been adopted in your book, and you should make sure first of what the authors opted for.


If A then it must be that B and that integer x is in set X


There is no ambiguity because "that integer x" is not a normal way to write "the integer x"; this has to be the case of "that" being the conjuction. If instead you had "that integer, x" then "that" is the demonstrative.

Thanks, I think I understand. So are each of the rewordings I offered at the end of my question equivalent to the statement If A then it must be that B and that C (I just corrected some mistakes in these rewordings)? In other words, could I use each of the rewordings and the statement If A then it must be that B and that C interchangeably? Or is there ambiguity in any of the rewordings I offered?

@Jonathan In those last three statements, according to the ellipsis, only the third is a correct form; the other two imply awkwad repetitions.

Okay so let A be set X is a strict subset of set Y, let B be x is in Y for each x in X and let C be |X| < |Y|. Would the compound statement If set X is a strict subset of set Y then it is true that x is in Y for each x in X and true that |X| < |Y| be correct form if the second occurrence of  true were removed? Or does it is true that also need to be changed to something like it must be that or it is the case that to remove all occurrences of true?

@Jonathan "If set X is a strict subset of set Y then it is true that x is in Y for each x in X and true that |X| < |Y|" is correct grammatically whether you use the second "true" or not. It is even correct if you add "it is", which makes for a more readily understandable statement, but you don't have to (matter of habit). (1/2)

@Jonathan  What I was talking about is this: if a letter (say K) stands for "K is true", then you must be consistent and when you say "if K" you  really say "if K is true". If K then (L and M) ---> If K is true then L is true and M is true. "If A then it is true that B and true that C" --->"If A  is true then it is true that B is true  and true that C is true".  It is possible that I misread the two statements above. So, they are all of the three correct statements. (2/2)

Ah I see! So to summarise, the second occurrence of that cannot be interpreted as a determiner if followed by a noun because it is not a correct way to refer to that noun. Hence, all three rewordings and the original ...it must be... form of the compound statement are unambiguous (interpreted as If A then (B and C)) if used correctly, and an example of incorrect usage would induce or imply awkward repetition. E.g. if A then it is true that B is true and true that...  or if A then it is both the case that it is the case that y is in Y and that... etc. Correct?

Per my comment under the question, it is possible to create (hypothetical) ambiguity around that. But I don't think this would ever be relevant to native Anglophones, except as a "linguistic parlour trick"

@Jonathan I am having a hard time following you, but right away I can tell you that "if A then it is true that B is true and true that" is not the most usual transliteration of "A ---> (B & C)"; there are two abnormal things: 1/ the reading of the  symbols is not consistent (A, B is true), 2/ it is complicated. "If A is true then B and C are (both) true" is one convenient way. Another is "If A is true then the conjunction of B and C is true".

Sorry, I wasn't consistent in treating A, B and C as placeholders in my last comment. I intended to confirm I understood your last comment. So for example, if A is x is even, B is y is true and C is z is odd then the first rewording I offered if x is even then it is true that y is true and true that z is odd introduces awkward repetition and is therefore incorrect. But the third rewording I offered if x is even then it is both the case that y is true and that z is odd is correct because repetition is avoided (1/2)

Similarly, if instead B is y is a prime number then the first rewording I offered if x is even then it is true that y is a prime number and true that z is odd is correct because the awkward repetition is avoided. Furthermore, your answer explains that for any of the rewordings the second that is unambiguously part of a that-clause. So if x is even then it is true that y is a prime number and true that z is odd can only be interpreted as if x is even then it is true that (y is a prime number and true that z is odd). Have I understood all of that correctly? (2/2)

@Jonathan I wouldn't say that it is incorrect, and occasionally you might say it (for instance so as to underline the functional nature of the transcription) but in most cases you have to simplify, as this becomes rapidly difficult to handle. so, "If x is even then it follows that y is prime and that z is odd". // "if x is even then it is both the case that y is true and that z is true": I'd reword this one as (small modification) if x is even then it is the case that both y is true and that z is true."

@Jonathan "if x is even then it is true that y is a prime number and z is odd": here, "that" is necessary, otherwise what you read is "(A ---> B ) & C; so, "if x is even then it is true that y is a prime number and that z is odd". // Finally, yes, that is the only interpretation.

@LPH Okay so all the wordings we've discussed are technically correct and unambiguous as long as any use of a in place of a is true is consistent (same with b, c, etc.) and you always have the second that. But simplifying by choosing wording carefully is strongly advised, and avoiding awkward repetition is a key part of this (e.g. your use of  it follows in place of it is true reduces the repetition of is and true etc.).


So am I correct about the that being ambiguous in these examples?

No: Because context.

So am I correct about the that being ambiguous in these examples?

"I think that rice is a good crop" (is it all rice or some specific rice). –
Stuart F
Yes: Because no context.
